# remove field name in Legend

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I have a graphic in Plotly. 
[image]

The legend includes the field name (`text_capitalise`) as well, and I only want the actual text/category (`Pringles`).

The code can be seen below.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(df, x= 'x', y= 'y', range_x=[0, 1], range_y=[1, 0], hover_data=[“start_time", "text"], color=“text_capitalise”)
```